# Confused about namespace scope!

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

I'm getting confused about the scope of 'using namespace' declarations... hoping someone can clear this up for me!

I'm using two libraries (OpenCV and Ogre3D). I have two cpp files, one uses exclusively OpenCV (PoseEstimator.cpp) and the other exclusively Ogre3D (OgreLogic.cpp).

The top of OgreLogic.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "PoseEstimator.h"
#include "OgreLogic.h"

using namespace Ogre;
```

And the top of PoseEstimator.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "PoseEstimator.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
```

This 'using namespace cv' is the **only** occurrence in the whole project (I double checked by doing a search).  The are no 'using namespace's in headers, only ever in cpp files.

However, when compiling OgreLogic.cpp I get ambiguity errors, e.g.:

> cxmat.hpp(3465) : error C2872: 'uchar'
>   : ambiguous symbol 1>        could be
>   'd:\libraries\opencv2.1\include\opencv\cxtypes.h(154)
>   : unsigned char uchar' 1>        or
>   'd:\libraries\ogresdk\include\ogre\OgrePrerequisites.h(106)
>   : Ogre::uchar'

I seem to be misunderstanding something, because I think this should be OK?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what is happening is you have a line declaring a `uchar`, e.g. `uchar x = 12` or something. At the top of your file, you've specified that you're using the Ogre namespace. The compiler is running into a problem determining which `uchar` you're using - the cxtypes.h one or the Ogre::uchar.

Try taking out the `using namespace Ogre;` and do your function calls as `Ogre::doStuff()` to remove ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for you help.

I 'solved' the problem by changing the uchar reference in cxmat.hpp (an openCV header) to unsigned char.

Seems to be working now!

Comment: Posted too soon by accident, tried to press enter to make a new line but was caught out!

Answer (score 1):

The root problem is that the `uchar` in cxtypes.h is **not** in the cv namespace.  The `uchar` in the OrgePrerequisites.h **is** in the Orge namespace (hence Ogre::).  By adding `using namespace Ogre;` you are actually making any reference to `uchar` ambiguous.

As spbots noted, you can remove the namespace usage to solve your problem, but I wanted to address your root question about namespaces.  The answer/issue is that the other uchar (the cxtypes one) isn't in a namespace at all.  It is simply declared in the header file outside of any namespace.